# How to parse a command-line in the same way that VBScript does

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, visual-c++

I have a simple C++ program that lists the arguments it gets:

```
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    for (int i = 1; i < argc; i++) {
        std::cout << argv[i] << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I'm just testing/figuring this out but the ultimate intention is for this to accept the names of some files and directories.

So I pass it these arguments:

```
"\\server\directory\file.ext" "C:\trailing\backslash\" "file.txt"
```

But this is what's printed:

```
\\server\directory\file.ext 
C:\trailing\backslash" file.txt
```

i.e. the trailing slash on the second argument makes it think the closing quote is escaped.

I'm setting the arguments in the property pages of VS2017, but I get the same output when:

- I call the exe from PowerShell.
- I allow an external tool to pass my
  exe arguments that it has built (which will be how this is ultimately
  used).

How can I get my program to understand that the quoted path with a trailing slash is one argument?

**EDIT**
Section 4 of [this article](http://www.daviddeley.com/autohotkey/parameters/parameters.htm) describes exactly my problem. Basically I want to make my C++ program interpret arguments in the same way that a batch file or VBScript does. **I cannot change how the arguments come in to my program**

**EDIT** I will simplify the question:

The C++ program above behaves like this:
[image: The C++ program above behaves like this]

I want it to behave like this:
[image: I want it to behave like this]

What do I have to do to the program or compiler in order for that to happen?

Comment: The article [Everyone quotes command line arguments the wrong way](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/twistylittlepassagesallalike/2011/04/23/everyone-quotes-command-line-arguments-the-wrong-way/) presents function `ArgvQuote()` that you can use to quote arguments correctly (whether or not it has a trailing backslash). This is something the caller of your program has to respect. Otherwise it's a bug in *their* program!

Comment: Both of those articles are about how to correctly quote and escape characters in a command line that you're creating. I'm talking about the resulting content inside argv being rubbish when my program is given a pretty standard Windows style quoted argument that many programs can deal with (a path with a trailing slash with quotes around it)

Comment: There is a de facto standard of how command-line arguments are parsed that is defined by the Microsoft C runtime and `CommandLineToArgvV`. This de facto standard requires to double a backslash, if it is followed by a double-quotation mark. If the programs you are talking about can deal with unescaped backslash, they are parsing command-lines in a non-standard way (e. g. by calling `GetCommandLine()` and doing manual parsing.

Comment: Looking at the source code for an open source project (7-Zip as it happens) I can see non standard parsing going on if compiled on WIN32. How disappointing. SplitCommandLine gets called from main... Oh well... https://github.com/kornelski/7z/blob/master/CPP/Common/CommandLineParser.cpp

Comment: I took the liberty to clarify your question title to make it clear from the beginning, what you want.

Comment: Use `GetCommandLine()` and parse it however you want.

Answer (score 3):

You have to protect the trailing backslash with another backslash, otherwise the backslash is treated as an escape character for the following double quote.
See this [blog post](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20100917-00/?p=12833) by Raymond Chen for a rationale for this behavior.
Here is a quote of the relevant part:

> - A string of backslashes not followed by a quotation mark has no special meaning.
> - An even number of backslashes followed by a quotation mark is treated as pairs of protected backslashes, followed by a word terminator.
> - An odd number of backslashes followed by a quotation mark is treated as pairs of protected backslashes, followed by a protected quotation mark.

Answer (score 1):

I tried compiling this with an extra slash to the second argument like below and was able to produce the desired output !

`"\\server\directory\file.ext" "C:\trailing\backslash\\" "file.txt"`

This was the output

```
/home/a.out                                                                                                                          
\server\directory\file.ext                                                                                                           
C:\trailing\backslash\                                                                                                               
file.txt
```

Upvote my post if it helps you :D

Comment: Here is a [detailed explanation](http://www.daviddeley.com/autohotkey/parameters/parameters.htm#WINCRULESDOC) of C++ command-line parameters.

Comment: I agree, but what if I'm not in control of how the arguments are built?

Comment: @Jobbo _"but what if I'm not in control of how the arguments are built?"_ You can always check if the command line parameter has a trailing backslash  and consider that situation in your program code, easy like that.

Comment: Can you elaborate on how I'd do that in C++?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ It's not that easy to deal with such bad input. Consider `"C:\path with spaces\"`. The C runtime will split this into these arguments: `C:\path`, `with`, `spaces"`. It's not clear how to "fix" such input, if possible at all. It's the job of the caller to fix *their* program by quoting properly.

Answer (score 0):

If you are not happy with the command line parsing you can do it by your own:

Just use [GetCommandLine](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683156%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) and parse your command line as you want it.

Other post already described how the command line is/should be treated (see [blog post of Raymond Chen](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20100917-00/?p=12833/)).